# lightning:recordform is not refresh after onsucess still shows old data

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

i used LDS to get child recordid from parent record and `lightning:form` to show/edit for child object record, after successfully update the child record still shows old date in `lightning:recordform` even though after successfully fire the `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire()`

cmp

```
<aura:attribute name="RecEventrecord" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="fields" type="String[]" default=" 
   ['field1__c','field2__c','field3__c']"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.parentrecord.child__c}" action="{!c.doInit}"/> // not working even though i fired init handler in refresh event
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}" /> // not working with this also
 <force:recordData aura:id="precord"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetFields="{!v.parentrecord}"
                  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                 recordUpdated ="{!c.loadeventhandler}"/>


  <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.parentrecord.child__c))}">
      <lightning:card class="slds-card_boundary">
          <lightning:recordForm density="comfy"
                 recordId="{!v.parentrecord.child__c}"
                 objectApiName="child__c"
                 fields="{!v.fields}"
                 columns="4"
                 mode="view"
                onsubmit="{!c.handleEdit}"
                onsuccess ="{!c.handleEditsuccess}"
                onerror = "{!c.handleError}"/>
     </lightning:card>
```

**cmpcontroller.js**

```
handleEditsuccess : function(component,event,helper){
          $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

In your recordUpdated handler (loadeventhandler) you need to reload the record manually

```
if(eventParams.changeType === "CHANGED"){
    component.find("precord").reloadRecord();
}
```

Here is the related documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_handling_record_change.htm

Comment: i am not updating parent record, i think u understood different way, i am updating child record via`lightning:recordform` i am using LDS for parent record details. u r answer is not useful